# show multiple position or maker on google map android when i click button at first page

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

```
private void showMaps() {
    Button mapButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapButton);
    mapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            latlngs.add(new LatLng(12.334343, 33.43434)); //some latitude and logitude value
            for (LatLng point : latlngs) {
                options.position(point);
                options.title("someTitle");
                options.snippet("someDesc");
                googleMap.addMarker(options);
            }


        }
    });
}
```

i want to achieve that when i touch a button. it will link to google map and show multiple position which select from a array list. when i do the debugging the latlngs is null. i do not not what happens.
[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wygoj.jpg)

Comment: In the image, where is googleMap?

Comment: when user touch the map button it will run google map and show multiple position which i set for example, Melbourne central, finder station and so on. however, the google map can not run when i touch the button. so, i can not catch the picture of google map.